# no tag appear on the right side of the screen when reviwing

Tags: support, tags, review

When reviewing suggested edits, no tag appear on the right side of the screen. What should I do? Will tags disappear?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The question's tags are only shown once.

If changes to the tags were suggested, they appear highlighted in green (added tags) or red (removed tags).